# HINT: $a^2+b^2=c^2$ cannot hold for $a,b$ odd and $c$ even. (using congruences)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Here is what I have: Suppose the contrary. Thus,

(2k+1)(2k+1) + (2j+1)(2j+1) = (2p)(2p)

Take mod 2 of both sides

[1][1]+[1][1]=[0]

[2]=[0]

[0]=[0]

No contradiction ... am I approaching this correctly? I want to figure this out myself but would like a small hint

Comment: You might try mod 4

Comment: Well, you can try another reduction. For example mod 4.

Comment: thank you! I just realized that too.

Comment: You might want to note that odd squares leave remainder $1$ when divided by $8$ (and not just by $4$). I'm sure you will be able to prove that. It sometimes comes in handy to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $a$, $b$ odd we may write

$a = 2m + 1, \tag 1$

$b = 2n + 1; \tag 2$

then

$a^2 = 4m^2 + 4m + 1, \tag 3$

$b^2 = 4n^2 + 4n + 1, \tag 4$

$a^2 + b^2 = 4(m^2 + n^2 + m + n) + 2; \tag 5$

also,

$c = 2p, \tag 6$

whence

$c^2 = 4p^2; \tag 7$

if

$a^2 + b^2 = c^2, \tag 8$

then substituting in (3), (4) and (7) we find

$4(m^2 + n^2 + m + n) + 2 = 4p^2; \tag 9$

we reduce this modulo $4$ and obtain

$2 \equiv 0 \mod 4, \tag{10}$

a contradiction which shows there are no such $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: thank you! i did the same